# In Jira-Domo integration, issues with more than 1 sprint show as closed in the first sprint

Tags: pm-software, jira, tools

We set up DOMO to pull from our Jira issues. We noticed that the Velocity charts were not matching up. We realized that for issues that are rolled into more than one sprint - if they weren't complete in sprint 1, they will be rolled into sprint 2 - when closed, DOMO will count their point values for velocity against the first sprint in the list, instead of the last.

There doesn't seem to be a clean, consistent way to use JQL to find the sprint an issue transitioned to Done in. And DOMO doesn't appear to have the flexibility to sort sprints by date within an item's metadata.

Has anyone approached this before?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used DOMO, but regarding:

> There doesn't seem to be a clean, consistent way to use JQL to find the sprint an issue transitioned to Done in.

Can't you just get the 'Resolved' field? It holds the date at which an issue's Resolution was set.

Regarding:

> All we want is the last sprint the item was in; we can assume it was closed in that sprint.

You can use the 'Sprint' field, which lists all sprints that issue was in, separated by commas. I don't believe there's a way in JQL to get *just* the last sprint, but it should be straightforward enough to write a program/macro/excel formula/whatever to split on ',' and get the last one.

Comment: Perhaps, but we want to know the sprint the item was completed in. We might be able to calculate that from the date, but it would be pretty kludgy. All we want is the last sprint the item was in; we can assume it was closed in that sprint.
We're thinking about using the Sprint ID from the XML, again assuming that the highest ID number will be the last sprint it was in.

Comment: yeah, i was hoping there was a built-in way to get the last sprint, rather than having to build something, that then needs maintenance, etc.
Also, technically, they're not comma separated, at least in the underlying XML. Each sprint gets its own entry in the Sprint custom field:
`<customfield id="customfield_10007" key="com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-sprint">
<customfieldname>Sprint</customfieldname>
<customfieldvalues>
<customfieldvalue id="162">PD 2017 Q4 S1</customfieldvalue>
<customfieldvalue id="167">PD 2017 Q4 S2</customfieldvalue>
</customfieldvalues>
</customfield>`

Comment: @MaxCascone Right. Like I said, haven't used DOMO. They're comma-separated if you use JIRA's JQL issue search. Either way, AFAIK there's no way out of the box to get the last Sprint, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, at least it's good to know I'm not missing a solution due to ignorance. FWIW, the XML i pasted is from Jira, not Domo.